# Add a line between files on my email Body -Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add a line between each file that were downloaded/copied or moved on my Email  Body at the moment:

I tried to use the following:

```
   "<br> "  , "", or htmlBody
```

but did not work

Here's where I need help with :

```
  $SMTPBody += 
        "Downloaded $($downloaded.Count) files:`n" +
        ($downloaded -join ", ") + "`n" +
        "latest being $($latestName) with timestamp $latest.`n"
}
```

Output:

```
  file1, file2
```

Goal:

```
file1
file2
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to add a "`n" when i declared the  variable $downloaded. It was a silly mistake on my end but heres what i did:

Changed

```
   $downloaded += $download.FileName
```

to:

```
 $downloaded += $download.FileName + "`n"
```